How can I show all information in a table search
I have created a table (well I got it of W3Schools) and have altered it slightly. When I do a search for say BMW it works as intended, but what if I want to search for BMW but want all the details of the Manufacturer, Model and Colour shown?
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<title>Car Hunter</title>

<style>

#mainTable {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

#td, th {
  border: 1px solid brown;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

#myInput {
width: 100%;
font-size: 16px;
padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
border: 1px solid green;
margin-bottom: 12px;
}

#mainTable tr a {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-top: -1px; 
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: black;
  display: block
}

</style>

</head>

<body>

<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for food items.">

</br>

<table id="mainTable">

<tr>
    <th>Manufacturer</th>
    <th>Model</th>
    <th>Colour</th> 
  </tr>

<tr>
<td><a href="#">Ford</td>
<td><a href="#">Capri</td>
<td><a href="#">Brown</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><a href="#">BMW</td>
<td><a href="#">M3</td>
<td><a href="#">White</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><a href="#">DAF</td>
<td><a href="#">XD</td>
<td><a href="#">Yellow</td>
</tr>

</table>

<script>
function myFunction() {
var input, filter, mainTable, td, a, i, txtValue;
input = document.getElementById("myInput");
filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
mainTable = document.getElementById("mainTable");
td = mainTable.getElementsByTagName("td");
for (i = 0; i < td.length; i++) {
a = td[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
td[i].style.display = "";
} else {
td[i].style.display = "none";
}
}
}

</script>

</body>

</html>


I tried various things but nothing would work for me. Is there a way to keep the code similar to what it is but with alterations to make it work?
